# Argument not specified for parameter 'SiteId' of 'Public Overridable Overloads Function Fill(dataTable)

Tags: vb.net

> Error: Argument not specified for parameter 'SiteId' of 'Public Overridable Overloads Function Fill(dataTable As LCSRDBDateSet.SampleDataTable, SiteId As String) As Integer'

How can I solve this? Pls help. This is not my own code. I'm studying other else's code.

```
If String.IsNullOrEmpty(reportFilter) Then daSample.SetWhereClause(String.Format("cdr_site_id = '{0}' AND cdr_datetime BETWEEN '{1}' AND '{2}' AND cdr_extension_no IN({3}) AND cdr_call_type_id IN({4}) GROUP BY cdr_extension_id", siteId, startDateTime, endDateTime, callClass, callType))

Else
    Dim filters2 = reportFilter.Split(",")
    Dim ta2 As New LCSRDBDataSetTableAdapters.SampleTableAdapter
    Dim dt2 = ta.GetData(siteId)

If filters.Count = dt.Rows.Count Then
    daSample.SetWhereClause(String.Format("cdr_site_id = '{0}' AND cdr_datetime BETWEEN '{1}' AND '{2}' AND cdr_extension_no IN({3}) AND cdr_call_type_id IN({4}) GROUP BY cdr_extension_id", siteId, startDateTime, endDateTime, callClass, callType))
Else
    daSample.SetWhereClause(String.Format("cdr_site_id = '{0}' AND cdr_datetime BETWEEN '{1}' AND '{2}' AND cdr_extension_no IN({3}) AND cdr_call_type_id IN({4}) GROUP BY cdr_extension_id", siteId, startDateTime, endDateTime, callClass, callType))
End If

End If

daSample.Fill(dtSample)
rdsSample.Name = "LCSRDBDataSet_Sample"
rdsSample.Value = dtSample
rvScreen.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rdsSample)
```

Comment: If an error message tells me that an argument hasn't been specified for a parameter of a method, I usually fix the issue by specifying an argument for that parameter of that method.

Comment: you call : daSample.Fill(dtSample) but in hte error message you can see : Public Overridable Overloads Function Fill(dataTable As LCSRDBDateSet.SampleDataTable, SiteId As String) As Integer'  so :) call daSample.Fill(dtSample, '1') where 1 is string = SiteId

Comment: @jmcilhinney Can you tell me how? I am new with VB.net

Comment: @CristiC777 hi. I tried it. But there's an error prompting. It says "Expression expected." pointing to the comma(,) symbol after dtSample

Comment: @CristiC777 I've changed it to "1". But it says,
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL version for the right syntax to use near "WHERE cdr_site_id='' AND cdr_datetime BTW' at line 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a few mistakes:

```
  If String.IsNullOrEmpty(reportFilter) Then      daSample.SetWhereClause(String.Format("cdr_site_id = '{0}' AND cdr_datetime BETWEEN '{1}' AND '{2}' AND cdr_extension_no IN({3}) AND cdr_call_type_id IN({4}) GROUP BY cdr_extension_id", siteId, startDateTime, endDateTime, callClass, callType))

  Else
      Dim filters2 = reportFilter.Split(",")
      Dim ta2 As New LCSRDBDataSetTableAdapters.SampleTableAdapter
      Dim dt2 = ta.GetData(siteId)

  If filters.Count = dt.Rows.Count Then
      daSample.SetWhereClause(String.Format("cdr_site_id = '{0}' AND cdr_datetime BETWEEN '{1}' AND '{2}' AND cdr_extension_no IN({3}) AND cdr_call_type_id IN({4}) GROUP BY cdr_extension_id", siteId, startDateTime, endDateTime, callClass, callType))
  Else
      daSample.SetWhereClause(String.Format("cdr_site_id = '{0}' AND cdr_datetime BETWEEN '{1}' AND '{2}' AND cdr_extension_no IN({3}) AND cdr_call_type_id IN({4}) GROUP BY cdr_extension_id", siteId, startDateTime, endDateTime, callClass, callType))
  End If

  End If
```

1. First is not escaped corret,  
2. you mix vb with C# 
3. your error is generate by : "cdr_site_id = '{0}' AND cdr_datetime BETWEEN '{1}' 
because {0} and {1} is not defined or isNull

Pls learn by this examples: 
[VB.Net - Database Access](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/vb.net/vb.net_database_access.htm) 
[Programming Tutorials - VB.NET Tutorials](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/74114-a-really-simple-database/)

use google to find vb.net tutorials
Good Luck!! and work hard :)

Comment: Sorry. I'm new to this language. :( and I was not the one who started this program. Btw, thank you.